# Faster way to read the files from server

Tags: tcl

I am using the below method to read a set of text files(>1000) and create a table out of that.
The file is of text type and file size is in KBs.

```
foreach serverfile $serverfile_list {
set fileport [open $ptffile r]
    #...........< other programming code to process on the data>
}
```

This is taking huge time about 2hrs to read.
Is there any way this can be made faster.

Appreciate your inputs and suggestions.

Comment: Are you using a package to make the table? I've seen sqlite read a file faster than using `open`, although it creates a temporary file during the reading and inputting the data into a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a great many things that might be going wrong here; the problem is *not* necessarily in the code lines you posted. (You should remember to `close` the file handle once you're done with it; you're remembering to do that, yes?)

In general, Tcl usually behaves in a single threaded fashion. That lets you get code working relatively easily (multithreaded is *much* harder!) That means you can work out the expected time to process all the files — assuming they all take about the same length of time — by taking the time to process one of them and multiplying by the number of files. If that gives you hours, your first issue is going to be figuring out how to speed up the processing of one file (and we'd need a lot more info to help you out). It might possibly even be that hours is how long it must take.

The other things it could be would be if the network is saturated between the processing system and the file server. (The more data you have, the more important it is to pay attention to this sort of thing.) Or there could be network contention. Tracking these sorts of things down is very hard indeed! However, if you copy a typical file to the local disk and compare the time to process it with how long it takes for it when it is remote, you can get a handle on how much the network (or the remote server) is to blame for the time taken.

Finally, it's possible that your code is doing something that is super-linear based on the number of files. Tcl has efficient algorithms to make this unlikely with simple operations such as building up an array, `append`ing to a string or `lappend`ing to a list, but that doesn't automatically mean that your code will be right. (There's a bug in `lappend` in 8.6.1 that makes adding several elements at once very expensive with long lists — there's an accidental triggering of quadratic behaviour instead of the normal amortized linear — which I've fixed for the not-too-long-off 8.6.2. A workaround is to use several `lappend` calls, each of which adds one element.)

In all cases, *we can't guess what is wrong without plenty of information!*

Comment: Yes I do close after each file operation. When I copy the files to local system it takes hardly 30mins which is fair and is okay.  I will check all the suggestion made network speed, lappend..) to see if this can help to improve overall. again thanks much for looking into this.